# Ruby on rails - Static method

Tags: ruby, oop, static-methods

I want a method to be executed every 5 minutes, I implemented whenever for ruby (cron). But it does not work. I think my method is not accessible. 
The method I want to execute is located in a class. I think I have to make that method static so I can access it with `MyClass.MyMethod`. But I can not find the right syntax or maybe I am looking in the wrong place.

Schedule.rb

```
every 5.minutes do
  runner "Ping.checkPings"
end
```

Ping.rb

```
def checkPings      
  gate =  Net::Ping::External.new("10.10.1.1")
  @monitor_ping = Ping.new()

  if gate.ping?        
    MonitorPing.WAN = true
  else 
    MonitorPing.WAN = false
  end

  @monitor_ping.save      
end
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

To declare a static method, write ...

```
def self.checkPings
  # A static method
end
```

... or ...

```
class Myclass extend self

  def checkPings
    # Its static method
  end

end
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the latter example, `def checkPings extend self`. Is this valid syntax?

Comment: Your class has to extend self to make all methods static inside of the class.

Comment: @Ashish are you sure it shouldn't be `class MyClass < self`?

Answer (score 61):

You can use static methods in Ruby like this:

```
class MyModel
    def self.do_something
        puts "this is a static method"
    end
end
MyModel.do_something  # => "this is a static method"
MyModel::do_something # => "this is a static method"
```

Also notice that you're using a wrong naming convention for your method. It should be `check_pings` instead, but this does not affect if your code works or not, it's just the ruby-style.

Comment: You should change the name of your method as suggested - it does matter when you look back at this code in a while. And it matters to someone else who has to also read that code - usually to figure out the (any) code doesnt work (who is used to the regular style - which is everyone I know programming in Ruby).

Answer (score 13):

Change your code from

```
class MyModel
  def checkPings
  end
end
```

to

```
class MyModel
  def self.checkPings
  end
end
```

Note there is self added to the method name.

`def checkPings` is an instance method for the class MyModel whereas `def self.checkPings` is a class method.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of extending `self` for the whole class, you can create a block that extends from self and define your static methods inside.

you would do something like this :

```
class << self
#define static methods here
end
```

So in your example, you would do something like this :

```
class Ping
  class << self
    def checkPings
      #do you ping code here
      # checkPings is a static method
    end
  end
end
```

and you can call it as follows : `Ping.checkPings`

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to declare a static method in RoR.

#1

```
class YourClassName
  class << self
    def your_static_method (params)
      # Your code here
    end
  end
end
```

#2

```
class YourClassName
  def self.your_status_method
    // Your code here
  end
end
```

Answer (score -16):

You cannot have static methods in Ruby. In Ruby, all methods are dynamic. There is only one kind of method in Ruby: dynamic instance methods.

Really, the term *static method* is a misnomer anyway. A static method is a method which is not associated with any object and which is not dispatched dynamically (hence "static"), but those two are pretty much the *definition* of what it means to be a "method". We already have a perfectly good name for this construct: a *procedure*.

Comment: downvote; semantics. Ruby's methods may not be "static", but the OP just wants a class level function (eg. MyClass::doThing()) which is totally doable in ruby. "You can't do that in ruby" isn't helpful.

Comment: Correct, but super nitpicky on the term "method". You know what they meant.