# How do people at Ruby think they will get away from static members? (Also: Tips for Java immigrant)

Tags: ruby

I was on #ruby on Freenode getting some real advice on how Ruby is different from Java yesterday, when someone pointed out that Ruby has no static members. I was really surprised.

Can anyone tell me what's is the substitute for using static methods (static variables can be duplicated using @@)(Someone told me to use a better design in the program rather than using archaic concepts like static functions.)

PS: Are there any other sources/tips/links you would recommend for a Ruby learner with prior Java experience?

Currently on: Beginning Ruby page 36.

Comment: Class methods, aka "static" methods can be defined like so inside a class: `self.i_am_a_method_on_self_and_some_call_me_static`. Ps. Are you enjoying Ruby so far? :)

Comment: I think this question is eligible for a migration to Programmers. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @andrew I am sorry if that offended you. Or anyone else. (Its just one)
@bazzz My first question on Stack Overflow. I am sorry
@Zabba Yeah. I will get back to learning it later in the evening. Thanks.

Comment: Ruby has methods that function similar to static methods.  They are 'class methods.'  The distinction isn't so important, from the start.  In fact, I can't recall where I've needed the distinction in my usage of Ruby.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out "how Ruby is different from Ruby".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr answer: Give it time and embrace the differences, it will come to you eventually.

> Are there any other sources/tips/links
>   you would recommend for a Ruby learner
>   with prior Java experience?

Yes, forget want you learned so far and start from scratch. I've been teaching Ruby courses on RubyLearning.org since January 2009 and regularly it's the people with only a Java background that have the biggest trouble adjusting to Ruby. Since I don't have much Java experience, I can't really say why that is, but the observation holds in every single new course.

It just seems to me that many Java developers assume that the way things are done in Java is the only way/the right way for some reason. But in a lot of regards programming languages are like real languages. Some are very close and concepts (and grammar) translate easily between them. Others are very different, but that doesn't mean they are not able to express the same things. Asking "how do you get away without static members" is like a German speaker asking a Chinese person how they get away without using grammatical cases, it's just the way the language works. Generally it's a bad idea to say "programming language X has this, how do I do that in language Y", but try to find out how things are generally done in Y.

After this rant, here are some more practical tips:

If you are interested in books, I usually recommend "The Well-Grounded Rubyist", followed by "Eloquent Ruby" and "Ruby Best Practices". I blogged about this not too long ago:

http://citizen428.net/blog/2011/04/23/ruby-book-recommendations/

Another thing I'd recommend is writing a lot of code, be in with the Ruby Koans, programming katas or contributing to an open source project. While doing so try to let Ruby's features influence the design, not your Java program. This may be hard at first, but I've seen people improve a lot in a really short time (our courses are 2 month long) by embracing the differences between the languages instead of forcing one to be like the other. Programming is a way too think about and solve problems, languages are just tools. You've obviously learned the first already, now try to apply it to different languages, following different paradigms.

You may have heard that it's good learn one new programming language per year. I don't particularly care about the time interval, but learning a new language is quite likely to make you a better coder in some way, as it often forces you to tackle problems from a new angle, thus increasing your "problem solving vocabulary".

Comment: Thank you very much. Especially for your blog link and Koans and Katas. (Heard about them for the first time)

Answer (score 0):

You actually can define static methods in Ruby. I think that it's just the naming that is different in Ruby.

```
class MyClass
  def self.static_method
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: This is an example of a Class method.

Comment: The name is slightly different, but it's the same idea as a Java static method.

Comment: Class methods are not static. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231534/ruby-on-rails-static-method/5235849#5235849

Answer (score 0):

I recommend *The Ruby Programming Language* by Flanagan and Matsumoto. Section 7.1.15 discusses Class Variables and section 7.1.16 discusses Class Instance Variables.

Section 1.1.9 discusses Ruby Suprises. For Java programmers, the surprise is strings are mutable. (Also everything is classed).

Using the interactive shell, irb, try the following

```
$ irb
>> "abc".class => String
>> "abc".methods => ["upcase!", "zip", "find_index", "between?", "unpack", "enum_slice", "to_f", "minmax", "lines", "sub", "methods", "send", "replace", "empty?", "group_by", "squeeze", "crypt", "gsub!", "taint", "instance_variable_defined?", "match", "downcase!", "take", "find_all", "min_by", "bytes", "each_cons", "entries", "gsub", "singleton_methods", "instance_eval", "to_str", "first", "chop!", "intern", "nil?", "succ", "capitalize!", "take_while", "select", "max_by", "chars", "enum_cons", "tr!", "protected_methods", "instance_exec", "display", "sort", "chop", "tainted?", "dump", "method", "include?", "untaint", "instance_of?", "chomp!", "swapcase!", "drop", "equal?", "reject", "hex", "minmax_by", "sum", "hash", "private_methods", "all?", "tr_s!", "sort_by", "chomp", "upcase", "start_with?", "succ!", "kind_of?", "strip!", "freeze", "drop_while", "eql?", "next", "collect", "oct", "id", "slice", "casecmp", "grep", "strip", "any?", "delete!", "public_methods", "end_with?", "downcase", "%", "object_id", "is_a?", "scan", "lstrip!", "cycle", "map", "member?", "tap", "type", "*", "split", "insert", "each_with_index", "+", "count", "lstrip", "one?", "squeeze!", "instance_variables", "__id__", "frozen?", "capitalize", "next!", "each_line", "to_enum", "rstrip!", "to_a", "ljust", "respond_to?", "upto", "each", "inject", "tr", "slice!", "class", "reverse", "length", "enum_with_index", "rpartition", "rstrip", "<=>", "none?", "instance_variable_get", "find", "==", "swapcase", "__send__", "===", "min", "each_byte", "enum_for", "extend", "to_s", "rjust", "index", ">=", "size", "reduce", "tr_s", "<=", "clone", "reverse_each", "to_sym", "bytesize", "=~", "instance_variable_set", "<", "detect", "max", "each_char", "each_slice", ">", "to_i", "center", "inspect", "[]", "reverse!", "rindex", "partition", "delete", "[]=", "concat", "sub!", "dup", "<<"]
>> "abc".gsub("b","B")
=> "aBc"
>> "abc".object_id
=> 2149174040
>> "abc".object_id
=> 2149162340
>> "abc".object_id
=> 2149155460
>> a = "abc"
=> "abc"
>> a.class
=> String
>> a.object_id
=> 2150044120
>> a.object_id
=> 2150044120
>> a.object_id
=> 2150044120
>>
```

Pretty cool eh?

Comment: Right. A few of these examples are in the book I am reading. Will check the later ones (object_id)

Answer (score 0):

If you understand "static method/attribute" as "class method/attribute" then Ruby definitively has them.

Ruby class methods are defined using `self`:

```
class MyClass
  def instance_method
    ...
  end

  def self.class_method
    ...
  end
end
```

Class variables can be created using the `@@` notation. Beware though - [they are shared along all the hierarchy of classes](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/).

Two notes:

- In Ruby, *classes themselves are instances* (of the class `Class`). On this sense, class methods are not really different from instance methods; they just have a slightly different syntax to simplify the common use case.
- In Ruby everything is dynamic. This means that at any point in execution time, a piece of code can "re-open" a class and add or modify an existing method - be it an instance or class method. If you understand "static" as "immutable" or "final", then Ruby has no such thing.