# Declaring Class Method with RubyInline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inline

I have the following lines of code in my `test_func.rb`

```
require 'inline'

class TestFunc
  inline do |builder|
    builder.c '
      int testfunc() {
        return 0;
      }'
  end
end
```

I am able to call the function only from an object and not class.

I can call it as,

```
obj = TestFunc.new
obj.testfunc()
```

But how should i declare so that i can call as,

```
TestFunc.testfunc()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on rails - Static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231534/ruby-on-rails-static-method)

Comment: my problem here is: `testfunc()` is a C function here. not sure how to relate that with ruby static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Inline::C#c_singleton`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/RubyInline/Inline/C.html#method-i-c_singleton) instead of [`Inline::C#c`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/RubyInline/Inline/C.html#method-i-c):

```
require 'inline'

class TestFunc
  inline do |builder|
    builder.c_singleton '
    int testfunc() {
      return 0;
    }'
  end

end

TestFunc.testfunc() # => 0
```

According to the documentation:

> **c_singleton**: Same as c, but adds a class function.