# Why instances don't have 'Class' as a parent in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
p 'a'.class.ancestors #=> [String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
p String.class.ancestors #=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Suppose I call a method on 'a'. It first goes and looks for that object in the String class, if it doesn't find it there, it looks in Comparable etc.

Now if I call a method on the Class class, it first goes to 'Class', then 'Module' etc.

What I don't understand is this. Why, when I call a method on an instance of a string like 'a', it doesn't look-up the methods in 'Class'? Why doesn't 'a' have Class in its ancestors list?

Comment: Because a string is not a class ;-) How on earth could you possible treat a *string* as a `Class`, for example getting its `ancestors`?

Comment: 'a' is not a class but also String is not a class, it's an object of class Class...

Comment: `String` *is* a class, meaning it's an instance of `Class`. `'a'` is not a class, meaning it's not an instance of `Class`. What do you call "a class" if not instances of `Class`?

Comment: `String` being an object of `Class` class is exactly what it means by `String` being a class.

Comment: It's worth noting that `String.singleton_class.ancestors` returns `[#<Class:String>, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `'a'` is not a `class`, `'a'` is a `string`, that's why `'a'` is an instance of the `class` `String`. `String` is a `class`, so it's an instance of the `class` `Class`.

Keep this in mind, `Class` is **not** and ancestor of `String`. `Class` is the `class` of `String`.

When you call a method on `'a'`, ruby will try to find that method in `'a'`'s class `String` and its **ancestors**, none of which is `Class`

### More Discussion

Normally speaking, when we are not having such abstract discussion, you'd say `'a'` is a `String`, or `String` is a `Class`. But that might lead to confusion in the current context.

This is because the `is a` relationship in current context could mean at least two different thing. `x` is a `Y` could either mean that object `x` is an instance of class `Y`, or it could mean that class `x` inherits from class `Y`. (of course naming conventions would suggest that `x` is an object and `Y` is a class.. but those are not solid enough)

This vagueness of the `is a` relationship is the root of the confusion here. Because in ruby, all classes are also objects, objects of type `Class`. To make the whole situation both confusing and elegant at the same time, `Class` is also an object! ...of type `Class`!!

```
[7] pry(main)> 'a'.ancestors
NoMethodError: undefined method `ancestors' for "a":String
from (pry):7:in `__pry__'
[8] pry(main)> 'a'.class.ancestors
=> [String, Comparable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
[9] pry(main)> String.ancestors
=> [String, Comparable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
[10] pry(main)> String.class.ancestors
=> [Class, Module, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
[11] pry(main)> Class.ancestors
=> [Class, Module, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
[12] pry(main)> Class.class.ancestors
=> [Class, Module, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

So if we were to simply talk in terms of `is a` relationship. `String` is a `Class` and a `String` is a `Comparable`. But `String` doesn't inherit from `Class`, it's an instance of `Class`. And `String` is not an instance of `Comparable`, it inherits from `Comparable`.

Now is a good time to refresh the meaning of the **inherits from** relationship. `String` inherits from `Comparable`, that means that all objects of type `String` will also inherit behavior from class `Comparable`. And since `String` does not inherit from `Class`, object instances of type `String` won't inherit any behavior from class `Class`.

Back to "is a" relationship. `String` is an `Object`. Now this applies to both relationships. `String` certainly inherits from `Object`. But also `Class`, what `String` is an instance of, inherits from Object. And thus String also inherits the behavior of class object. So when we say `String` is an `Object`, it could mean either of the things. Although, if we were talking about inheritance, we'd probably say "a `String` is an `Object`", meaning that instances of class `String` are also objects. While saying "`String` is an `Object`" (notice I dropped the article 'a') we'd mean that the class `String` itself is an object.

I just realized something else. Remember how we declare static methods in Ruby? [Ruby on rails - Static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231534/ruby-on-rails-static-method)

You say...

```
class X
  def self.static_method
    ...
  end
end
```

If you think about it, by using the keyword `self`, we are referring the object nature of `X`. So when later you call `X.static_method`, you are accessing `X` as an object and referring to an instance method associated with object `X`.

Hope I've not confused you guys too much.

Comment: `'a'` is not a *String*. It is an instance of *String*. You could say `'a'` is a *string*.. :-) same also applied for `String` is `Class`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit It's common to say "$value is a $Type". Like 5 is an int (sorry, a Fixnum), eve is a Person, 'a' is a String. "`'a'` *is* `String`" would be misleading, but "is a" is a far shot from that.

Comment: The whole point is here - `ancestors` will list the *class* names in the list, only when there is possibly at least on which the respective *receiver* has a chance to invoke. Otherwise or *NOT*.

Comment: I'm still thinking of ways to make this answer mor clear

Comment: @Spundun I wrote one answer, but I deleted as I saw yours. Mine has may be 30% more information than you.. But I will give you hints to make your answer more valid.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be updating after half an hour.

Comment: If you call `Array.ancestors
# => [Array, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`... See here - `Array` itself came in the list... Why? Because `Array` has some methods, like `::[]`, `::new`, which you can call anytime, on `Array`, thus for *method look up* sense, it is the responsibility for the method *ancestors*, to bring the class `Array` in to the list. Same for `Hash.ancestors`.

Comment: @delnan I've tried to deal with your comments in the discussion that I've posted above.

Comment: Yes, your job is done. :-) +1. one more thing *type of String*.. Umm...Ruby don't understand the language *type*, but it follows a convention - *"If it walks 
like a duck, and quacks like a duck, I'll happily treat it as a duck."*

Comment: @ArupRakshit true... it's so hard to find the right words for describing these concepts. BTW, I was about to step out to run to work when the comments started, and I had been intending to write this discussion once I reached at work. So I said I'll write in half an hour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55012/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-spundun).